# mysql group by in correct sum and missing data issue

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum

I am trying to generate a report for results per campaign_name, and sum totalCommissions and totalDeposit amounts, 
the amounts are in decimal 8, 2 format.

the result returned is not what I expect.
thanks

```
select t.campaign_name, 
       count(distinct t.uuid) as visits, 
       count(distinct l.uuid) as leads,
       count(distinct r.uuid) as registrations,
       count(distinct c.uuid) as ftd,
       sum(amount) as totalCommissions,
       sum(deposit_amount) as totalDeposits 
from trackings as t  
    left join (
       select uuid 
       from leads 
       where leads.lead = 1
    ) as l on l.uuid = t.uuid 
    left join (
       select uuid 
       from registrations 
       where registrations.registration = 1
    ) as r on r.uuid = t.uuid 
    left join (
       select uuid,
              trader_id 
       from conversions 
       where conversions.ftd = 1
    ) as c on t.uuid = c.uuid 
    left join (
       select trader_id, 
              amount,
               sum(amount) as totalCommissions 
       from affiliate_commissions group by trader_id
    ) as ac on ac.trader_id = c.trader_id 
    left join (
       select transaction_id,
              trader_id, 
              deposit_amount, 
              sum(deposit_amount) as totalDeposits 
       from transactions  
       group by trader_id
    ) as tr on tr.trader_id = c.trader_id 
 where `t`.`created_at` between '2015-03-01 00:00:00' and '2015-03-24 23:59:59' 
    and `aff_id` = '2' 
 group by `t`.`campaign_name'
```

expected result should aggregate by campaign_name:

```
created_at,campaign_name,visits,leads,registrations,ftd,totalDeposits,totalCommissions
2015-03-17 23:50:11,defaul,2,2,2,2,1100.00,4.32
    2015-03-15 18:25:38,new_campaign_name,1,1,1,1,300.00,
    2015-03-18 10:44:48,new_test,1,0,0,0,,
```

current output results:

```
created_at,campaign_name,visits,leads,registrations,ftd,totalDeposits,totalCommissions
2015-03-17 23:50:11,defaul,2,2,2,2,100.00,
2015-03-15 18:25:38,new_campaign_name,1,1,1,1,300.00,
2015-03-18 10:44:48,new_test,1,0,0,0,,
```

Comment: It is almost impossible to receive help if your query is unreadable.

Comment: what do you mean?  tables structure?

Comment: no, I mean the query that you pasted into question was un-readable. Most of it was off the screen.

Comment: thanks Hunter for the edit, i got that now ;)